# Why is Marshal.AlignedSizeOfStruct<T> being used instead of Marshal.SizeOfStruct<T> in SafeBuffer.WriteArray<T> and SafeBuffer.ReadArray<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, unmanaged

According to http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/safebuffer.cs

`SafeBuffer` uses the aligned size of the struct type rather than the actual size of the struct type. It appears this causes alignment issues when writing what needs to be a densely packed array of structures and when reading from a preexisting densely packed non-aligned array of structures in the buffer. In the first case, the use of the aligned rather than the actual size results in unwanted padding bytes. In the second, the data gets mangled. I have two questions (4 really, but 3 are related):

1. Is there a way around this other than manually aligning access using sequential calls to `SafeBuffer.Write<T>` / `Read<T>` (which is slower), or ditching the `SafeBuffer` class (and therefore the quite nice `UnmanagedMemoryAccessor` class) entirely?
2. What are the reasons behind this choice? Why is the CLR enforcing it's own alignment requirements on unmanaged memory? Why should this not be considered a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Hmya, answers to these questions are invariably subjective, we don't have the .NET Framework designers contributing here to pass their design meeting notes to us.  But you can safely assume that this is *not* a bug and this was pained about a great deal.  Surely at least one of the reasons that it took so long for MMFs to be supported in .NET.

Everybody loves to ignore or wish away structure packing and alignment details.  The CLR does a very terrific job of hiding them.  But the buck stops here, no way to ignore them anymore.  The cold hard fact is that it is entirely impossible to make everybody happy.  The framework has no reasonable way to guess what the code on the other side of the MMF looks like.  It is unknowable, MMFs are entirely too simplistic to support anything like metadata.  With one clear failure mode of having a 32-bit process on one end and a 64-bit process on the other.  They use different alignment choices, 4 vs 8.  Many more, particularly if its is native code on the other end using its own #pragma pack.

Given that the framework can never get it 100% right, they chose to *at least* make it right and efficient when .NET code runs on either side.  An entirely reasonable choice.

The only real flaw is that the documentation is lacking.  You *will* have a headache when you need to interop with native code.  Trial and error is, right now, the only good way.  Or asking a question about the *specific* problem you have at SO of course :)

Comment: _"The framework has no reasonable way to guess what the code on the other side of the MMF looks like"_
A. I'm not using a memory mapped file. I'm using a custom SafeBuffer subclass that wraps around some unmanned memory. 
B. If the CLR can't guess, it could at least give the client the ability to specify what kind of alignment it wants. The fact that I'm supposed to be able to set the size and memory layout of a struct through the StructLayoutAttribute suggests that it'll be respected when converted to a pointer.

Comment: You are of course talking to the wrong person.  Call Microsoft instead.  Or just write your own version of SafeBuffer.

Comment: I was coming here to see if I was off base or not. Sorry if it seems like I'm argumentative. I may end up talking to Microsoft and writing my own version anyway. Thanks for the help.